# Text input to web page without text fields

Tags: javascript, html

Can a web page detect keyboard input without text input fields or with text input fields unfocused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an event listener to the document
(run the example, and click on it to activate it, otherwise its document won't have the focus, this is intended to work on a standalone page rather than embedded frame)

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownCallback, false);

function keydownCallback(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode + ': "' + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + '"');
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? I press letter and I see letters, I press numbers and I see numbers. Which ASCII characters cannot be read?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onkeydown` handler on `document`, you just need to have the focus on the window.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            console.log('left');
            break;
        case 38:
            console.log('up');
            break;
        case 39:
            console.log('right');
            break;
        case 40:
            console.log('down');
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: I rather use console.log() than alert(), it is less annoying